# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jackson, apache-kafka-streams

I'm running into exception while running Kafka stream Java app in IntelliJ-Idea IDE with Avro serde.
Same topic/app runs without problems in JSON format.

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JacksonFeature    at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:655)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.(ObjectMapper.java:558)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.utils.JacksonMapper.(JacksonMapper.java:24)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.(RestService.java:151)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:153)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.configureClientProperties(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:83)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.configure(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:56)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:50)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.configure(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:58)

So I've changed all possible jackson pacakges several time - no luck.
I see that jackson-databind is called but I don't see it present in confluent registry.
So I used `jackson-bom` in my `pom` file - changed all major versions still no luck.

### Project relevant files

**POM file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pmu</groupId>
    <artifactId>PMU_StreamingAPP_Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <confluent.version>7.0.1</confluent.version>
        <kafka.version>3.0.1</kafka.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Avro plugin for generating pojo-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Confluent Kafka Avro Serializer-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Kafka Clients-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Log4J2 binding for SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Topic Avro schema (PosInvoice):**

```
{
  "namespace": "guru.learningjournal.kafka.examples.types",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "PosInvoice",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "InvoiceNumber","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "CreatedTime","type": ["null","long"],"default" : null},
    {"name": "CustomerCardNo","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "TotalAmount","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "NumberOfItems","type": ["null","int"]},
    {"name": "PaymentMethod","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "TaxableAmount","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "CGST","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "SGST","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "CESS","type": ["null","double"]},
    {"name": "StoreID","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "PosID","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "CashierID","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "CustomerType","type": ["null","string"]},
    {"name": "DeliveryType","type": ["null","string"]}
  ]
}
```

### Kafka stream code that breaks app:

**Stream creates/loads ok:**

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, PosInvoice> KS0 = builder.stream(AppConfigs.posTopicName,
        Consumed.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.PosInvoice()));
```

**But after that this code breaks app:**

```
KS0.filter((k, v) -> v.getDeliveryType().equals("Home_Delivery"))
    .to(AppConfigs.shipmentTopicName, Produced.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.PosInvoice()));
```

It seems that stream is serialized OK but after that code breaks on `KStream.filter` method.

Comment: The BOM doesn't actually import the libraries. What errors do you get if you actually add databind dependency? And did you try a lower version of the Avro serde?

Comment: @OneCricketeer None - compiles ok and throws same error with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.2.2

Comment: @OneCricketeer and yes, I've tried all combinations of lower versions of avro serde. Been rotating them with other dependencies whole day yesterday..

Comment: Hmm, well, `kafka-streams` has a transitive dependency on databind. The error you're getting is for jackson-core class

Comment: I had jackson-core in dependency as well together with jackson-annotations and several others. Changing them all for same versions and changing versions - didn't help.  Actually I don't think they are need at all since confluent repository is pulling all relevant dependencies with proper versions.

Comment: Where can I find what jackson-core, jackson-databind and  jackson-annotations specific confluent platform is using?

Comment: You can start at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka or https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry , or you can just decompile the JARs in the IDE, or use `mvn dependency:tree`